# Diagrama de sectores en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy haciendo pruebas con el dataset esoph

```
datos<-esoph
```

He cogido la variable agegp (que son los grupos de edad) y he intentado hacer un diagrama de sectores con los porcentajes que he calculado así:

```
prop.table(table(datos$agegp))*100
```

Para hacer el diagrama de sectores:

```
porcentaje<-c(17.0,17.0,18.2,18.2,17.0,12.5)
label<-paste(porcentaje,"%",sep = "")
color<-c("lightblue","pink","green","yellow","grey","blue")

pie((prop.table(table(datos$agegp))*100), 
    col = color,
    main = "PORCENTAJES AGEGP",
labels = label) 

legend("topright", c("25-34","35-44","45-54","55-64","64-74","75+"), cex=0.7, fill = color)
```

Me gustaría saber, para este diagrama con porcentajes, he tenido que crear, los porcentajes en una variable (de forma manual), label (para poder separar el porcentaje y añadirle el símbolo de porcentaje (%) y una leyenda aparte, añadiendo los datos manualmente...

**¿Habría forma de hacerlo más sencillo y menos manual?**
**¿Se podría hacer con ggplot usando las *variables agegp y ncases*, por ejemplo?**

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, tienes, me parece, un problema de concepto, `table()` y `prop.table()`  trabajan sobre las frecuencias y no sobre la sumas de `ncases`, por eso los porcentajes son tan similares. Me parece que lo que buscas es más bien algo como esto:

```
library(tidyverse)
datos %>% 
  group_by(agegp) %>% 
  summarise(ncases = sum(ncases)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(ncases))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  agegp ncases   pct
  <ord>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 25-34      1 0.005
2 35-44      9 0.045
3 45-54     46 0.23 
4 55-64     76 0.38 
5 65-74     55 0.275
6 75+       13 0.065
```

Es decir, una agrupación por `agegp` y la suma de `ncases`. Con estos datos, se puede construir fácilmente un gráfico de barras, que ciertamente es mejor al clásico gráfico de torta:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(agegp) %>% 
  summarise(ncases = sum(ncases)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(ncases)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=agegp, y=pct, fill=agegp, label=scales::percent(pct))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),
          vjust = -0.5,
          size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

---

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ggplot** no tiene de forma nativa un gráfico de tortas, pero no quiere decir que no se pueda construir uno, simplemente es un poco más de trabajo, ya que, si queremos los porcentajes, deberemos precalcular las coordenadas dónde estos deberán aparecer:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(agegp) %>% 
  summarise(ncases = sum(ncases)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(ncases), 
         lab.ypos = cumsum(pct) - 0.5 * pct) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=pct, fill=agegp, label=scales::percent(pct))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = scales::percent(pct)), color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void()
```

---

El Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias por su respuesta. Todo más claro ahora. Que pase buen día. Saludos